# configure.ac: not using gettext

Tags: automake, autoreconf

I am trying to compile a gnome application and I am curious what the output means when I run the `autogen.sh` script:

```
~/Documents/Code/window-picker-applet $./autogen.sh
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal 
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: running: libtoolize --install --copy
libtoolize: Consider adding `-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoheader
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --no-force
data/Makefile.am:11: `%'-style pattern rules are a GNU make extension
data/Makefile.am:11: wildcard $(top_srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
data/Makefile.am:11: (probably a GNU make extension)
autoreconf: Leaving directory `.'
[Output trunkated...]
```

Why am I getting the info `configure.ac: not using Gettext`? Is that a warning and should I change some of the configuration files to fix it? I know the application has a `po/` folder so I think it should be using Gettext, hence I am confused about this warning.

<s>I also had a lot of warnings with the `N_` macro not being defined, so this might be related?</s> **[Update]** See comment below **[/Update]**

Comment: The issue with the N_ macros not being defined was because the neccessary include (glib/gi18n.h) was missing. This had previously been in included with another include file (gtk/gtk.h) but it was removed in the latest gtk+ version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your `autogen.sh` is calling `autoreconf`.

The project may be using `intltool` instead but if so `autoreconf` should pick that up and call `intltoolize`. If it's definitely using GNU gettext then this from the `autopoint` info page is helpful:

> The ‘autopoint’ program copies standard gettext infrastructure files
>   into a source package.  It extracts from a macro call of the form
>   ‘AM_GNU_GETTEXT_VERSION(VERSION)’, found in the package’s
>   ‘configure.in’ or ‘configure.ac’ file, the gettext version used by the
>   package, and copies the infrastructure files belonging to this version
>   into the package.

And if we write `AM_GNU_GETTEXT_VERSION` then `autopoint` is correctly invoked by `autoreconf`.

> To extract the latest available infrastructure which satisfies a
>   version requirement, then you can use the form
>   ‘AM_GNU_GETTEXT_REQUIRE_VERSION(VERSION)’ instead.  For example, if
>   gettext 0.19.8 is installed on your system and ‘0.19.1’ is requested,
>   then the infrastructure files of version 0.19.8 will be copied into a
>   source package.

The problem only appears when switching to this version of the macro, and while it does what it says on the tin it isn't known to `autoreconf` and we see a [patch for support](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/autoconf-patches/2015-10/msg00001.html).

Gentoo users can get the same behaviour in ebuilds by [using our `eautoreconf` function.](https://github.com/gentoo/gentoo/pull/163)

Writing `AM_GNU_GETTEXT_VERSION` and `AM_GNU_GETTEXT_REQUIRE_VERSION` immediately afterwards in my own `configure.ac` generates a warning but otherwise appears to yield the desired result.

Answer (score 6):

What OS?

Likely your system does not have all or some of the gettext system, namely the development portions. In many distributions, e.g. Debian/Ubuntu, gettext is separated into multiple packages: `gettext-base` and `gettext`.

The `gettext-base` package is for running programs which are multi-lingual, while `gettext` has the necessary parts for building.

Comment: I am running on Ubuntu (11.10). Gettext is installed but not gettext-base.

Comment: I am dealing with patching (via src code + ./configure) an old Fedora built platform with more code, and I'm running into this problem.  Installing gettext, and the re-./configure on autoconf/autogen/m4 hasn't helped so far.  I notice that pkg-config doesn't think getttext is installed.  But, I notice that pkg-config on more modern systems doesn't list gettext either, even when gettext-base is installed.